# How to draw circle in android by pressing a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I want to show small dots on screen while pressing a button, something like **pin** code...

```
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonNum1:
        editor.putString("PinNumbers",getString(R.string.numberOne));
        int x = 10;
        int y = 30;
        int r = 100;
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mCanvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,mPaint);
        break;
```

Comment: you are looking for the ripple effect right?

Comment: I want that when the user presses the button that appears small point to user can know when he pressed button. 
To be just like when you˙re typing pass with keyboard it shows you what you picked.

Answer (score 0):

> You can achive by creating ripple effect
>
> create one drawable name like pin_button_ripple in drawable-v21 folder and add bellow code

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Now in  Layout file set it as a background of button and define click listener in activity

> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/btnPinButton"
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:background="@drawable/pin_button_ripple"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:text="10"/>
> ```
>
> You will see the ripple effect in circle shape like we enter Pin
>   number or password via keyboard and showing that effect